# MlpPolicy only return 1 and -1 with action spece[-1,1]

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, policy-gradient-descent, stable-baselines, mujoco

I try to use Stable Baseliens train a PPO2 with MlpPolicy. After 100k timesteps, I can only get 1 and -1 in action.
I restrict action space to [-1, 1] and directly use action as control.
I don't know if it is because I directly use action as control?

Comment: What environment are you training it on?

Comment: @qwererer did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be the result of the gauß distribution PPO2 is using. You could use a different algorithm that doesn't use gauß or use PPO with another distribution.

Checkout the example here:
https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/issues/112
And this paper:
https://www.ri.cmu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/thesis-Chou.pdf